# Redefining macros with old contents / Making a file include counter

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to count the amount of includes of one specific file.

My first idea was to define a macro holding the count and redefining it when a specific file is included. I have to find a way that the macro is expanded, to be used in a new definition with the same name again, else its old value would simply be destroyed by undef. Is there a way to expand the macros when the macro is defined. Or is there an other way to count including files?

FILE main.c:

```
#define INCLUDE_COUNT 0

// some other files include the file include_counter.h here
```

You would think that the compiler could replace `INCLUDE_COUNT` by 0 or one of its redefinitions in the first line, but it doesn't because macros inside macro-definitions are expanded when the macro is used in non-macro code.

FILE include_counter.h:

```
#define OLD_INCLUDE_COUNT (INCLUDE_COUNT)
#undef INCLUDE_COUNT
#define INCLUDE_COUNT (OLD_INCLUDE_COUNT + 1)
// INCLUDE_COUNT would be expanded to ((INCLUDE_COUNT) + 1)
```

Comment: I think you've answered your own question as to why you can't do what you want.   Why do you want to do it?    What utility is there in counting the number of times a file is included?

Comment: I'll let someone smarter than I on macros cite the chapter and verse, but how is the compiler ever supposed to rely on the definition of a *constant* if you attempt to change it all the time?

Comment: The macro ``INCLUDE_COUNT`` is helping to set a specific name of a struct in a file, which is included multiple times, it should emulate a c++-template in c, only that it is built by including a file and defining the template-parameters by macros before the include and undefined after.

Comment: Look up the compiler specific `__COUNTER__` macro. It's supported by gcc and Microsoft compilers.

Comment: While I also want to have a linear increasing counter, which should be the count of includes, ``__COUNTER__`` increases outside the header, when otherwise used. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you're using GCC, the `-H` option reports on the names of the files that are included as they are included, including the nesting level.  Maybe that will allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to expand the macros when the macro is defined.

Yes.  But beware... using this as a means of generating unique symbols may cause unexpected linker issues if your symbols have external linkage.

### Overview

The key problem here is that macros are not variables.  With variables, if I have `x=3*3; y=x;`, then I'm assigning the *value* of x to y.  With macros, if I have `#define PPX 3*3` `#define PPY PPX`, then I'm literally assigning `PPX` to `PPY`.  If I then evaluate `PPY`, it expands to `PPX`, and then to `3*3` but only because `PPX` is currently defined as `3*3`.

However, there is a way around this.  The preprocessor can evaluate expressions; it just uses conditional directives to do so.  But due to the fact that this can branch, we can define macros *conditionally* based on `PPX's` *value* (as opposed to its *replacement list*).  For example:

```
#if (PPX)%10==9
#  define PPX_DIGIT_0 9
#elif (PPX)%10==8
#  define PPX_DIGIT_0 8
...
```

So whereas `PPY` critically relies on `PPX` being defined as `3*3` to expand to `3*3`; since `PPX_DIGIT_0` is *literally defined as `9`*, `PPX` can be undefined, and `PPX_DIGIT_0` will still expand to 9.  Note also that the conditional played a role in reducing the expression; `(3*3)%10` is just equal to 9, causing the 9 branch to be hit.  That loses the expression per se, picking up just the evaluation... which we want.

That's the idea.  In practice, this requires a fair amount of code; fortunately, boost's preprocessor library already has it done for you, so here are two approaches using boost:

### Approach 1: Using Boost Slots

**`include_counter.h`**:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/slot/slot.hpp>
#if !(INCLUDE_COUNT)
# define INCLUDE_COUNT 0
# define BOOST_PP_VALUE INCLUDE_COUNT
# include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(1)
# undef  BOOST_PP_VALUE
# undef  INCLUDE_COUNT
# define INCLUDE_COUNT BOOST_PP_SLOT(1)
#endif
#define BOOST_PP_VALUE 1+INCLUDE_COUNT
#include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(1)
```

Boost slots evaluate macros and store their results using special internal states.  You get 5 slots (code above is using slot 1), so you can store 5 numbers.  This solution just initializes the slot to 0 before incrementing on the first include, then essentially just increments.

### Approach 2: Use Boost Counter

**`include_counter.h`**:

```
#if !(INCLUDE_COUNT)
# include <boost/preprocessor/slot/counter.hpp>
# define INCLUDE_COUNT BOOST_PP_COUNTER
#endif
#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()
```

Same idea, though it "consumes" boost counter.

Both boost solutions take the approach I just described.  There's also a boost increment macro; feel free to ignore that, since (a) you're evaluating anyway, and (b) boost increment is a bit whimpy (with its maximum limit of 256).

You can also roll your own solution.  But when you're done, it's going to look similar to boost's solution anyway.  (The advantage is, your new "slot" will be independent of boost counter and boost slots).

Comment: I am more a coder, who makes the program stand-alone, so there are not much linkages. And even if it is used for linked symbols, this way is better than using __COUNTER__, which counting is not controlable like this.

Comment: @cmdLP Just to be clear, the _program_ being standalone doesn't matter per se; the risk is there if you are compiling multiple `.c` files _into_ a program.

Comment: If you only include the templatelike header-file in just one other header. It does not make problems, because all are always included and the counter is not changed anywhere else. (If multiple counters are used #pragma push/pop_macro("BOOST_PP_COUNTER") should help.

Comment: @cmdLP Based on this comment I still don't think you understand the issue.  The risk is that you unintentionally define two different things with the same name.  If you have multiple `.c` files, you're compiling each one separately (into a `.o` file).  Each such compilation being separate, the counter starts over.  The fact that you're using a counter suggests some probability of collision.  If you define two different things with the same name (two `.o`'s use the same symbol), and they have what's called "external linkage", you'll fail when you combine the `.o`'s together (link)...

Comment: ...this is something to be aware of in your design; this can come back and bite you when you least expect it.  Finally, there's no point in trying to convince me in these comments that you mitigated this risk; that's likely going to involve me seeing your code, and is beyond the scope of this question.  If you like, you can ping me in chat (if you can catch me); or submit your approach to the code review site.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is not to use the macros but the compiler.  Many compilers have a "show includes" flag.  For instance, in gcc, it is -H.  For visual studio, it is /showincludes.  Just pipe the compiler output to a file and count the number of lines.

```
# linux
gcc -H ... fred.c 1> incs.txt 2>&1
wc -l incs.txt

rem Windows
cl /showincludes ... fred.c 1> incs.txt 2>&1
find /v /c "" < incs.txt

# powershell
cl /showincludes ... fred.c 1> incs.txt 2>&1
get-content incs.txt | measure-object -l
```

Note that this will count the same file if it has been included multiple times, even though it does not get processed because of the guards.